# Find fields missing one out of two closing brackets in VS Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace

Using regular expressions in Visual Studio Code, I am trying to find fields in a .bib file (bibliographic references) that are missing one out of two closing curly brackets and that are followed by the Pagination field. In a .bib file, every field ends with a comma and a new line. In the example below, the first field (`Abstract`) matches these criteria.

```
@jurisdiction{InternationalFruit:1972fo,
Abstract = {{Text with all kinds of punctuation.?},
Pagination = {paragraph},
Ecli = {EU:C:1972:115},
Keywords = {eu},
Number = {5},
Title = {{International Fruit Company NV}},
Year = {1972}}
```

So I tried using a negative lookbehind, like this:

```
\{\{[\s\S]*?(?<!\})\},\n\tPagination
```

But this is greedy: it will include several fields in the match until it encounters a field that ends with a single `\}` and is followed by the `Pagination` field.

I thought that the first `?` would avoid that. Could anyone tell me

- how to do this correctly and
- why the `?` doesn't do what I thought it would do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match from `{{` to the first occurrence of `}` which is not preceded by a `}` followed by matching a comma and newline and assert `Pagination` on the next line.

```
\{\{.*?\}(?<!\}\}),\r?\n(?=Pagination\b)
```

The pattern will match

- `\{\{` Match `{{`
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possbiel
- `\}` Match `}`
- `(?<!\}\})` Assert what is on the left is not `}}`
- `,\r?\n` Match comma and newline
- `(?=Pagination\b)` Assert what is on the right is `Pagination`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZeJNg/1)

The updated pattern with the `\t`

```
\{\{.*?\}(?<!\}\}),\t\r?\n(?=Pagination\b)
```

Comment: Thanks, as this matches my line of reasoning I learned a lot from this. It works if I add a    `\t` to `,\r?\n`.  But would the `?` be really necessary there?

Comment: @TimothyRoes The point of `\r?\n` is that it matches CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings on Windows, as well as LF (`\n`) line endings on Linux.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is correct about the newlines. It also takes the `Pagination` into account on the next line as in your original pattern and you can match `}` in between if it is there.

Comment: @Thefourthbird  Indeed, this is the more complete answer as it also includes the Pagination field on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern seems to work:

```
\{\{[^}]+\}[^}]
```

This matches two opening `{{`, which are then followed by some content (*not* including a closing `}`), ending with a `}` which is not closed properly.

### Demo

Comment: That was very quick and this solution is both clever and elegant. Thanks!